# htaccess and regex redirects for multiple styles

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I want to redirect all of the following

```
example.com
http://example.com
https://example.com
http://www.example.com
```

to

```
https://www.example.com
```

I've got this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
RewriteRule ^/(.*):SSL$   https://%{SERVER_NAME}/$1 [R,L]


Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www.example.com
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/$1 [R=permanent,L]
```

These two below are working,

```
http://www.example.com 
https://example.com
```

but the last one shows up as:

```
https://www.example.com/https://example.com/
```

How can I correct this so all three redirect properly to https://www.example.com

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All that you want **can be done in a single rule** like this:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://www.example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NE,R=301]
```

Make sure this is very first rule in your root .htaccess.

Comment: YES! Thank you, you nailed first time out of the box. The nightmarish day I'm having is a lot better for your help.

Comment: You're most welcome, glad it worked. Have a nice rest of the day.

Answer (score 0):

```
^(?:.*?:)?(?:\/\/)?(?:.*?\.)?(.*?\.)(.*)$
```

Try this.Replace by

`https://www.$1$2`

See demo.

http://regex101.com/r/lU7jH1/6

Comment: thanks for that. Umm, since none of that looks anything like my original code, just where do you want me to stick that? :-)

From the demo, it looks like exactly what I need but I don't want to make too many mistakes in my .htaccess file. Could you please be more specific using my original code as a start?

Comment: Just because regex is able to match the given URLs doesn't mean this regex will work for `mod_rewrite` also.

Comment: @vks - Thanks for your trouble vks. I'm just too lame with regex to know what to do with it.

Comment: @AllThisOnAnACER unfotunately i dont havean knowledge of php :( ...just the regex.